# How can I select a dictionary according to the user's choice?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to use the user input to reference a dictionary, so that the user will choose which dictionary to use.

For example, given the dictionaries

```
cisco = {'uname': 'user_name', 'password': 'pass', 'backup_make': 'Write memory', 'backup_location_device': 'nvram:/startup-config'};
bnt = {'uname': 'user_name', 'password': 'pass', 'backup_make': 'save', 'backup_location_device': 'getcfg'};
ods = {'uname': 'user_name', 'password': 'pass', 'backup_make': 'None', 'backup_location_device': '/config/juniper.conf.gz'};
f5 = {'uname': 'user_name', 'password': 'pass', 'backup_make': 'tmsh save /sys ucs my.config.ucs', 'backup_location_device': '/var/local/ucs/my.config.ucs'};
hp = {'uname': 'user_name', 'password': 'pass', 'backup_make': 'save', 'backup_location_device': '/config.cfg'};
juniper = {'uname': 'user_name', 'password': 'pass', 'backup_make': 'None', 'backup_location_device': '/config/juniper.conf.gz'};
alteon = {'uname': 'user_name', 'password': 'pass', 'backup_make': 'save', 'backup_location_device': 'getcfg'};
```

I want to do something like

```
vendor = raw_input("Enter the vendor's name: ") 

print ("the username: " + vendor["uname"] +
       "; the password is: " + vendor["password"])
```

I want to use "cisco", "bnt", "ods", etc. as indices without using an `if` statement.

Thanks!

Comment: correct your data structure, use one more dict to nested all 7 dicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it the other way around?

```
vendors = {'cisco': {'uname': 'user_name'...}
           'bnt': {...}}
```

Then, do this:

```
requested_vendor = raw_input('Enter vendor name: ')
credentials = vendors.get(requested_vendor.lower())
if credentials:
    print('The username is {} the password is {}'.format(credentials['uname'],
                                                         credentials['password']))
else:
    print("Sorry, there is no vendor by the name {}".format(requested_vendor))
```

Answer (score 3):

Put them all inside a larger dictionary.

```
vendors = {
    'cisco': cisco,
    'bnt': bnt,
     ...
}

choice = vendors[vendor]
```

Comment: and how do i reference the individual fields inside the dictionary ?

Comment: I don't think "fixing" the wrong design decision of having built seven separate dictionaries is a good idea. @BurhanKhalid's solution is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a dictionary vendors with the key as the vendor name and the value as the vendor dict. value

```
>> vendors = {}
>> vendor1 = {'uname': 'xyz', 'pass': 'abc'}
>> vendor2 = {'uname': 'abc', 'pass': 'xyz'}
>> vendors['vendor1'] = vendor1
>> vendors{'vendor2']= vendor2

>> vendor = raw_input().lower()
>> if vendor in vendors.keys():
..     print "The username is " + vendors[vendor]['uname'] + 'and the password is' + vendors[vendor]['pass']
>> else: print "%s not found" %vendor
```